# SOS ( Material Help)

Tags: directx

OK.
I can load mesh into my project, but I can't change the mesh's color.
On the screen, the mesh's color is white.
I want to change it to red, but I can't.
Please help.

Here is my code:

```
g_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);

g_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
g_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG2, D3DTA_DIFFUSE);
g_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_DISABLE); 

g_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, FALSE);
g_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_DISABLE);  
g_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_DISABLE);
g_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(2, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_DISABLE);

D3DMATERIAL9        mtrl;

D3DUtil_InitMaterial(mtrl,1,1,1);

for(int j = 0 ; j < m_meshTarget[i].dwNumMaterial ; j++){       

    if( m_meshTarget[i].pnTextureIndex[j] != -1){
        g_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetTexture(0, m_meshTarget[i].ppTexture[m_meshTarget[i].pnTextureIndex[j]]);}
    else
        g_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetTexture(0,0);
        g_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetMaterial(&mtrl);
        m_meshTarget[i].pMesh->DrawSubset(j);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what `D3DUtil_InitMaterial()` does, but you need to set proper values for `mtrl` light properties.

```
float red = 1.0f, green = 0.0f, blue = 0.0f;

mtrl.Diffuse.r = 1.0f;
mtrl.Diffuse.g = 1.0f;
mtrl.Diffuse.b = 1.0f;

mtrl.Ambient.r = red;
mtrl.Ambient.g = green;
mtrl.Ambient.b = blue;

mtrl.Specular.r = 0.5f;
mtrl.Specular.g = 0.5f;
mtrl.Specular.b = 0.5f;

mtrl.Power = 8.0f;

g_pApp->m_pd3dDevice->SetMaterial(&mtrl);
```

The diffuse, specular, and power values are just for example.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it doesn't help me at all.

Comment: I can't understand the reason why the mesh's color is white.